# Слово болванка

Tags: значение-слов, история

По танку вдарила болванка
Погиб родимый экипаж.

А разве болванка не  снаряд без заряда? Как она могла повредить танку

Answer (score 2):

Вас интересует вопрос с точки зрения русского языка или военного дела? Если с т.з. русского языка. то Болванка - Разг. Неразрывной снаряд для пробивания брони, разрушения зданий и т.п. , т.е. это  бронебойный снаряд: литая металлическая болванка крушит все на своем пути. Вопрос ещё в том, куда она угодила.

В песне только один момент - пробитие брони, что само по себе уже повреждение, а если и башню снесло, и внутри всё покорёжило? Там же нет подробностей, а беды бронебойный снаряд может принести много и без взрыва, а уж если в пробитую броню ещё и фугас - точно не выживешь.Кстати, в этой песне, помнится, ещё и второй снаряд. и третий... Так что всё правдоподобно.